# Optgroup in drupal 7 list field

Tags: nodes, entities

Now I'm having like

1|City name
2|Another city name
3|Little town name

in values field when creating content type field

How can I wrap some of them in a group that will appear as “optgroup” in html generated?

Answer (score 13):

you can use a [hook_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and then add code like this:

```
$form['FIELDNAME']['#options'] = array (

   'parent1' => array(
      3 => 'child1',
      4 => 'child2',
      5 => 'child3',
    ),
    'parent2' => array(
      8 => 'child1',
      9 => 'child2',
    ),
);
```

Comment: How can I also add the #multiple parameter to a select element when using optgroups. When I try it my select box turns to a series of checkboxes with with the title array(). I have tried adding multiple as an attribute but then drupal does not recognise any of the selections and rejects the form as though I had failed to select an option.

Answer (score 5):

using forms api inside hook_form-alter function you can generate parent-child array then drupal_render will render dropdown.

```
    <? 
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {     

    if ($form['#form_id'] == 'my_nodetype_node_form') {    
    $parents = taxonomy_get_tree($vid = 2 /*vocaulary ID*/, $parent = 0, $max_depth = 1);

    foreach ($parents as $term) {
      $options[$term->name] = array();
      $children = taxonomy_get_tree($term->vid, $term->tid);

      foreach ($children as $child) {
        $options[$term->name][$child->tid] = $child->name;
      }
    }
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($options);die;
    $form['the_taxonomy_terms_field']['und']['#options'] = $options;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Clive. Saved me 1/2 hours work! May I confess, just caught myself copy pasting one of your answers *yet again* to close a task.

PS: I did work a *little* by posting this comment ... and obviously changing the form_id and field name of term reference ...  and swapped $vid variable for a constant  in the function call to taxonomy_get_tree as this vocab is used in other places for nodequeue interaction and such. But heck, you still did most the work!!!  Thanks friend. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is module for that called as [optgroup select](https://www.drupal.org/project/optgroup_select). You can try that module.

PS: I am the module maintainer.